# android-maps-extensions infoWindow doesn't show

Tags: android, android-maps-extensions

I need display >100 markers on the map and show info window after click on marker.
I have used android google maps api v2, but it is lagging with such number of markers. So I decided switch to android-maps-extensions. After I did it info window has stopped appear after click on marker.

Here is my code:

```
private void prepareMap() {
    SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.locationsMap);
    map = fragment.getExtendedMap();

    ClusteringSettings settings = new ClusteringSettings();
    settings.clusterOptionsProvider(new ClusterOptionsProvider() {
        @Override
        public ClusterOptions getClusterOptions(List<Marker> markers) {
            float hue = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED;
            BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(hue);
            return new ClusterOptions().icon(icon);
        }
    });
    settings.clusterSize(100);
    settings.addMarkersDynamically(true);
    map.setClustering(settings);

    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            // breakpoint here are working. marker is not null
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (map != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            Location location = new Location(cursor);

            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
            options.position( new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            options.title(location.getTitle()); // title is not null
            options.snippet(location.getAddress()); // address is not null
            options.data(location);
            map.addMarker(options);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? I have try use own InfoWindowAdapter, but it is not scaling this window for appropriate content, however I am using wrap_content attribute in xml.

Comment: Any reason you are returning `false` from `onMarkerClick`? Did it show **any** info window when you use `InfoWindowAdapter`?

Comment: @MaciejGórski when I return `false` then default behaviour like center map on marker is appear. When I use own `InfoWindowAdapter`  it shows fixed-size window with part on content.

Comment: You may remove `OnMarkerClickListener` if you do not have any code other than provided in your example, because showing info window is a default behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no support for setting title on `ClusterOptions` (yet), you will have to use `InfoWindowAdapter` (you may put a separate question on why it is not working as you want it) or add `title` to `ClusterOptions` yourself and make sure its value is forwarded to `virtual` marker that represents cluster. This sounds complicated but is fairly easy. You may also want to add issue on GitHub regarding title not being supported for clustrers.
After that you may use something like:

```
return new ClusterOptions().icon(icon).title("Test");
```

Then you will have to figure out what title will best fit your needs. You will most likely want to use `List<Marker>` to calculate title for this group of markers.

Note: If you zoom enough to show separate markers, you can click on them to show title. If not, there is something more wrong in your code.

Comment: Thanks for response. There is no info window even on max zoom. Anyway I'll fork repo on GitHub and will try to forward title to `virtual` marker.

Comment: @Vladimir If you change cluster icon color to `float hue = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE;` and find red markers (these will be markers you add and set title on them), they do not show the info window?

Comment: when I am using blue markers then red is not appears. Even on max zoom level.

Comment: @Vladimir Then that's the reason. All your markers are always clustered together. They must be too close to each other or you are adding every marker more than once.